# Alt+` (tilde or back tick) switch windows like alt-tab in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Peculiar that when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tilde</kbd> (tilde key just above tab key. If I type that key here in SuperUser compose window, the text format is changed), I'm shown a small menu like old <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but it only goes one step to the window which was being used previous to this active window. In other words, if I'm working Window1, and before that I was working on Win2, and before that 3, 4, 5. Then pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> will only let me switch between Win1 and Win2 (although it'll show all 5 windows tabs, but won't go to them).

I've checked my language bar shortcut settings, and in there 'Switch Input Language' has been assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and 'Switch Keyboard Layout' has not been assigned any shortcut (None).

I've tried capturing this key sequence in other windows. Like in MS Word Keyboard Customization dialogue, but that doesn't capture this key. I.e. that dialogue doesn't show this key has been pressed, rather Windows switcher is shown (like Alt+tab, but won't go to third window, will remain in two recent windows).

I also tried to capture this shortcut in Pulover's Macro Creator v5.05. But, though in PMC, Win10 didn't get the key presses (alt tab switcher wasn't shown), but nor did PMC get/show that key press (if I press alt and ` separately, then they are captured in PMC ok).

Then I tried installing another physical keyboard to my laptop (TVS Gold). But that keyboard also is behaving exactly same.

What should I do?

Comment: By /u/SilverseeLives:   

Ctl-Tab is the standard convention for switching between tabs or child windows within a single application, but of course, the application must support the behavior.

Multiple instances of a single app, to my knowledge, are not treated differently by the window manager and thus get switched with Alt-Tab like any other top level window.

Source: 

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/gcqnwq/simple_questions_thread_week_of_may_3rd_2020/fpspsq7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm extremely sorry that this undesired behaviour was caused because of a small folly on my side.

I happen to remap the key thru Auto Hot Key sometime and later forgot. And this 'behaviour of going only one step back' was caused by the the fact that only the first press of <kbd>Alt+`</kbd> was intercepted (and interpreted) by Ahk (to make Ahk interpret again, it needed me to release both Alt and tilde key and then press them again).

Comment: Probably as it's a self inflicted problem. If you think someone may have done the same as you, because the software makes it easy to do what you did specifically, then no - leave your question and mark your answer as an answer. *Is the software to blame?*

Comment: please mark your own answer as "accepted"